# Docker: Using apt-key with alpine image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to use alpine (nodeJS) docker image, but I do get the error `/bin/sh: apt-key: not found`. What do I have to add?

```
FROM node:8.6-alpine
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on my sample Dockerfile.

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine
RUN apk update \
    && apk fetch gnupg \
    && apk add gnupg \
    && gpg --list-keys
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use something as follows:

```
apk add --no-cache gnupg

gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
```

Answer (score -6):

There’s no `apt-key` on Alpine, this is something from Debian.